# File Upload Form not going into success when successful

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am submitting a file in my form in a dialog.

It is being submitted correctly; the file arrives perfectly fine on the server via the URL I am supplying.

As per [API description](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit) I should supply a **'success'=true** in the response if everything went right on the server. This is what I did, and this is what I see coming back :

[image]

This is what my code looks like. However even though I return success = true, it always goes to the **case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID**.

```
frm.submit({
    url: URLs.fileUploadURL,
    waitMsg: 'Uploading file...',
    success: function(form,action){
        alert('Success', 'Processed file on the server');
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {

        alert('FAIL : action.failureType ' + action.failureType)

        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID: //Always goes here :(
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
        }
    }
});
```

I do not understand this. Doesn't **success=true** mean that the success callback is going to be called?

Extjs documentation on 'file upload' is really atrocious. ExtJS in Action contains about one line about it. I have mainly gotten to where I am through trial and error and I have spent days on this. Is there any other documentation out there? Perhaps a couple of pages detailing how to use the 'file uploader' ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in wrong JSON that's being returned. I see that what's being returned is and object that has "success" and "msg" attributes, but what goes after them is.... another nested object?

Comment: yes, its more stuff thats not important. Is that not allowed?

Comment: It could somehow prevent "success" event from triggering (i.e. parser breaks in the middle of its way). Try to change it and you'll know for sure.

Comment: @AlekseiMialkin it worked. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Glad I could help you. Though you know, maybe I'll do it, just so the answer become "answered" and no help is required anymore, LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in incorrect JSON that's being received from the server. Remove curly brackets surrounding "files" and it will work.